# Notebook backlight partly working

Tags: laptop, display

I have a problem with my HP 350 G1 Notebook. Sometimes it happens that suddenly the right bottom corner of the screen gets slightly darker than the rest of the screen (please see attachment). Once I move the notebook a bit or close and open the screen again it usually works again.

So far I have no idea what the source of this issue might be. I've heart of many people having backlight problems, but as far as I understand this would lead to a completely dark screen.

The problem does not occur with an external monitor, so it is pretty sure that it is not a problem of the GPU.

Does anyone of you have an idea what the problem is and how to fix it? There is no more warranty on the device and I'd like to do the repair by myself.

[image: photo of screen issue]

Comment: Have you checked with a external monitor.

Comment: Yes I did, the problem does not occur with an external monitor.

Comment: Then your display might be the problem. Be very careful while changing the display, if you damage any part then you have to spend more money on it.

Comment: Sounds like the backlight is failing - or more specifically *one* of the backlight LEDs has a bad contact.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace it yourself, but it depends on your laptop. 1st step would be to check the manual/service guide and see if the display is indeed replaceable; they usually have detailed instructions about how to replace components. You also might want to find the LCD part number, so you can verify when you buy it that it is right part. I see it's an HP, so these links should help:

https://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/

http://partsurfer.hp.com/

Then you can search eBay or the like for a screen for your model number/part number. Once you have the screen it's just a matter of disassembling the laptop (using the service guide) and swapping the panel.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it really necessary to replace the entire LCD Display?

Comment: Assuming the backlight is the issue, then kinda...The backlight is contained in the LCD panel. Perhaps you can open it and replace the bulbs but I have never tried it. Also, I would imagine it is easier to obtain a whole LCD than it is to get just the bulbs.